# Preventing code under location variable from running until it is assigned

Tags: javascript

I have this code where I am essentially displaying a notice and upon clicking accept I am grabbing the geolocation of the user and then passing it to a function to get the proper cctld that the user should be redirected to, and assigning it to temp in the ccNoticeAccept.onclick function. The problem is I don't want anything else to run until I've grabbed the cctld and assigned some value to temp. Right now it will essentially run anything under the assignment regardless of whether the user accepts the browsers notification to grant access to location. How can I fix this so nothing under temp runs until a value is assigned? I've tried a couple methods but it didn't seem to work.

```
//RETURNING ccTLD CODE
function getcctld(code){
  switch (code) {
    case 'us':
      console.log('US detected');
      return "com";
      break;
    case 'ca':
      console.log('CA detected');
      return 'ca';
      break;
    default:
      console.log('No site detected for country');
      return "non";
  }
}

function getlocation(){
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    console.log("geolocation connected");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      $.getJSON('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse',{
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lon: position.coords.longitude,
        format: 'json'
      }, function(result){
           curcountry = getcctld(result.address.country_code);
           console.log("." + curcountry + " returned");
           return curcountry;
         });
    });
  } else {
     console.log("geolocation not connected");
     return "FAILED";
  }
}

ccNoticeAccept.onclick = function(){
  //if cookie notice accepted, set cookie and display country modal
  setCookie("cookieNoticeCC", 5, "TRUE");
  ccNotice.style.display = "none";

  let temp = getlocation();
  //don't do anything until country is returned

  //more code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the "callback hell" by promisifying `getCurrentPosition` and using `async`/`await` syntax:

```
const promisePosition = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    navigator.geolocation ? navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject) 
                          : reject("geolocation not connected")
);

async function getlocation() {
    let position = await promisePosition(); 
    let result = await $.getJSON('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse', {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lon: position.coords.longitude,
        format: 'json'
    });
    return getcctld(result.address.country_code);
}

ccNoticeAccept.onclick = async function() {
    //if cookie notice accepted, set cookie and display country modal
    setCookie("cookieNoticeCC", 5, "TRUE");
    ccNotice.style.display = "none";
    try {
        let temp = await getlocation();
        //don't do anything until country is returned
        console.log(temp + " returned");
        //more code
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getlocation` isn't returning anything. Anyway, you can solve this by passing a callback as a parameter to `getlocation`. Inside `getLocation` the callback function can be invoked with the country.

```
function getlocation(callback) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("geolocation connected");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            $.getJSON('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse', {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lon: position.coords.longitude,
                format: 'json'
            }, function (result) {
                curcountry = getcctld(result.address.country_code);
                console.log("." + curcountry + " returned");
                callback(curcountry);
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log("geolocation not connected");
        return "FAILED";
    }
}


ccNoticeAccept.onclick = function(){
    //if cookie notice accepted, set cookie and display country modal
    setCookie("cookieNoticeCC", 5, "TRUE");
    ccNotice.style.display = "none";
  
    getlocation((country) => {
        // everything that depends on `country` can be added here
        console.log(country)
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you! that solved it!